# How to make information from 2 tables match based on record value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing this in PHP and MYSQL it's used in a an ordering system, an order comes in with a specific item, I have a look up table that has a unique number I'm trying to sort by, I need to figure out a way to say if the item ordered matches the item in the table copy the id over to the order table like follows

Look Up Table

## item              ID

1    batman comic book  1111
2    superman comic     1112
3    spiderman comic    1113

Order table

## Ordered_item            Sort_ID

1          spiderman comic          NULL
2          batman comic book        NULL
3          superman comic           NULL

```
 $sort = "SELECT ordered_item, sort_id
        FROM order table 
            WHERE packing_slip_printed = 0 
    AND LOWER(payment_status) = 'completed' 
    AND address_name <> ''";
 $item_ids = "SELECT *
    FROM look up table";



$rows = $db -> fetch_all_array($sort);
$updaters = $db -> fetch_all_array($item_ids);
$itemname = $updaters['item']; 
$itemkey = $rows['sort_id'];
$updatekey = $updaters['ID'];
echo $updatekey;
if ($itemkey = NULL)
 { if ($updaters['item'] == $rows['item_name'])
     $itemkeys = $updatekey;
mysql_query("UPDATE `paypal_ipn_orders` SET `key` = '. $itemkeys .'");
}
```

I want to update the order table Sort_ID to match the ID from the look up table.

I figured I could use a nested if statement but Sort_ID just comes back 0

Comment: Did you test your mysql statements individually? The first statement looks like it's missing the where keyword and the first part of the where statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a step or two back and rethink everything you're doing.

1. Your sql is invalid (the $sort query lacks a WHERE keyword, at the very least)
2. You're apparently mixing mysqli/pdo and the mysql_* functions
3. Your table structure seems to lack proper references to link them together (why is sort_ID null and equally importantly - based on it being null - why do you expect it return something other than null or 0?)

Or maybe we're lacking a lot of info about the code you're trying to write.

Comment: The reason it is null is because null needs to be replaced with the 4 digit number from the look up table. The order comes in without the 4 digit number. all I really need to do is cross reference the 2 tables if it the item names match I need to copy the id from the look up table to order table oh and also I did leave the where out. It is WHERE packing_slip_printed = 0. It's not really relevant.